# How to create different shape in css?

Tags: css, css-shapes

[image]

I want to create a shape like the uploaded image wiht css. Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: try http://www.css3shapes.com/ and http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-different-shapes-in-css

Comment: That seems like an ordinary huge circle. Circles (even hollow, I think) are quite easy in CSS3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not difficult. You create a circle within a wrapper that clips out what you don't need.

## [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/4460868)

**HTML**:

```
<div class='shape-wrap'>
    <div class='shape'></div>
</div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.shape-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 32em; height: 8em;
}
.shape {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: -175% -50%;
    width: 200%; height: 800%;
    border: solid 2em dodgerblue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 .5em .25em dimgrey;
}
```